# Why Remmina closes when we select "share folder"? Linux Mint 16 KDE

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, kde, remmina

Why Remmina closes/crash when we select "share folder" in Linux Mint 16 KDE? Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue with Linux Mint 16. This is also reported here for Fedora: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=997592

The only solution I have found is manually edit the .remmina config file of the connexion (located in ~/.remmina/) and add the share folder in "sharefolder=" like this:
sharefolder=/home/username/

After connexion, the folder is share correctly.

Good luck!